# sum of 10 numbers in an array using try and catch block

Tags: java

I have problem about program to find the sum of 10 numbers in an array. it use try, catch block to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Please help me...

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Could you add your code, please?

Comment: If you're getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, I say you're doing something wrong

Comment: `it use try, catch block to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. ` I would delete that bit as you shouldn't need it.

Comment: Why would you need to handle ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception? When you know the size of your array?

Comment: The only way I can think of using an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in your code is using a `public int get(int index){ return yourArray[index]; }` and sending `index < 0` or `index >= yourArray.length`. Otherwise, your question has no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose correct program for ur code is

```
class ravindra {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ia = new int[10];
try{
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
            ia[i] = i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
            sum += ia[i];
        System.out.println(sum);
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
//system.out.println("exception");
}
    }
}
```

for occurance of exception loop ur code through the `for loop` until arraybound goes out of bound(i.e. arraylength+1)

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ia.length; i++)
```

Comment: Why you need try-catch block here, if you are checking for the index before hand?

Comment: thanks all give the comment~it was exercise giving by lecturer~first time i see sum the numbers using the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException~

Comment: Thanks to Ravindra~ i understand your coding~it sum total array from 0 until 9.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
int[] nums = new int[10];
// give it some values.
long sum = 0;
for(int n: nums) sum += n;

System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
```

You shouldn't need to catch an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @RohitJain Maybe because of the violation against the official java coding conventions. (It wasn't me though)

Comment: @Alderath based on the OP's next question, I suspect he really wants to catch an exception rather than fix the code so it doesn't throw it. AFAIK It follows the Java Coding Conventions. ;)

Comment: @Alderath Are you talking about braces on the loop? That's the only thing I can think of, but I was under the impression that is a _personal preference_ kind of thing...

Comment: @PeterLawrey The conventions dictate that you [put braces around all for-blocks](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#454) (and if-, while-, etc.-blocks).

Comment: It appears that its been updated since 1999. `//AVOID! THIS OMITS THE BRACES {}!` IMHO its not error prone if you have a formatter. ;)

Comment: @Alderath you're making a storm in a glass of water. If the **sample** code compiles, then you can use it the best way you need/want (this is, rewriting the code following the Java Code Conventions, adding your own variables, methods, etc).

Comment: I suspect Alerath was just trying to imagine the reason for the down vote. I suspect it was the OP looking to write sample code which catches an Exception based on the follow up question also about Exceptions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I added a comment in OP question about a code that could throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, is the only one that I can imagine, but still we don't know what OP needs or what would be his/her motivation for this question.